# read text file as dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

My text file looks like this..Each line separated by a space.

```
dream 4.345 0.456 6.3456
play 0.1223 -0.345 5.3543
faster 1.324 2.435 -2.2345
```

I want to write the dict and print it as below...

```
dream: [4.345 0.456 6.3456]
play: [0.1223 -0.345 5.3543]
faster: [1.324 2.435 -2.2345]
```

My code is below. Please correct me with this...

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
     for lines in file:
        line = lines.split()
        keys = b[0] 
        values = b[1:]
        d[keys] = values
print d
```

Comment: What is `b` and `d`?

Comment: I have answered this, please check. I have placed data into a dictionary and also created a string text as you have mentioned (which is not actually a `dict`).

Answer (score 0):

For python3, if u want to have desired result :

```
d = {}

with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    for lines in file:
    line = lines.split()
    keys = line[0] 
    values = list(map(float, line[1:]))
    d[keys] = values
for k in d :
    print(k , d[k])
```

Comment: Thank you. That's simple and easy.  I was struggling with converting the values to a list. so list(map) does that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. See the code below.

```
  dictionary = {}
  with open("text.txt", "r") as file:  
      for lines in file:
          line = lines.split()
          dictionary[line[0]] = line[1:]
  print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you. But this prints the values with comma separated which is not my desired  output

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

> input.txt

```
dream 4.345 0.456 6.3456
play 0.1223 -0.345 5.3543
faster 1.324 2.435 -2.2345
```

> writer.py

```
output_text = '' # Text
d = {} # Dictionary

with open("input.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        arr = line.split()
        name = arr[0]
        arr = arr[1:]

        d[name] = arr
        output_text += name + ": [" + ' '.join(arr) + "]\n"

output_text = output_text.strip() # To remove extra new line appended at the end of last line

print(d)
# {'play': ['0.1223', '-0.345', '5.3543'], 'dream': ['4.345', '0.456', '6.3456'], 'faster': ['1.324', '2.435', '-2.2345']}

print(output_text)
# dream: [4.345 0.456 6.3456]
# play: [0.1223 -0.345 5.3543]
# faster: [1.324 2.435 -2.2345]

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output_text)
```

> output.txt

```
dream: [4.345 0.456 6.3456]
play: [0.1223 -0.345 5.3543]
faster: [1.324 2.435 -2.2345]
```